# Native SQL query removes backslashs

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I stop my query string from being processed when query.getResultList is called or alternately set the schema name that includes a backslash?

Background info:
I have multiple schemas within a SQL Server database. I differentiate between these schemas based on the username. Default is `default.tableName` and individual users have `[Team\Username].tableName`

For my native query, I've got a select statement like "Select * from "+schema+".tableName";

I can see the string that is created within the Org.hibernate.query.internal.nativeQueryImpl class and it looks fine. The statement runs in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
select * from [TEAM\Username].tableName;
```

However when the query object calls getResultList(), I get the following error:

> "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
> ResultSet"
>
> caused by
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name
> 'TEAMUsername.tableName'.

As you can see the backslash and square brackets are being removed during processing. This query works if I use the default schema as aka default.teamName

I've tried a few different ways to escape the characters but as I mentioned, I can see that the query has been set within the Query object correctly.

Comment: have you tried `select * from "[TEAM\Username]".tableName;`

Comment: `For my native query` ... Why are you concatenting the table name into the query string?  In general you should probably avoid putting backslashes into the table names.

Comment: "Ive tried a few different ways to escape the characters but as I mentioned, I can see  that the query has been set within the Query object correctly."
What exactly have you tried? I would try a double backslash `[TEAM\\Username].tableName`

Comment: I've tried the `[TEAM\\Username].table` however i'm yet to try `select * from "[TEAM\Username]".tableName;`. I managed to get it working by changing the schema names to team_username in combination with `....{h-schema}tableName ....`